# Which tense is correct for this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I often write

> Article A was published in a paper which was non-reputable. [1]

However, I want to know if

> Article A was published in a paper which **is** non-reputable. [2]

is grammatically correct. Also, does it sound natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical.
If the paper is still "non-reputable" then by all means use "is". But if there is any doubt about whether it is still current, or is remote from anyone's current attentions then I would use "was".